# List the contents of a local folder from within swf

Tags: actionscript-3, flash

I have succesfully read a file from the local computer in as3, I would like to know if it is possible to list the contents of a folder in some way. The swf will run from browser and acces local files only. No server, no outside world contact. 
this is how I have accesed and displayed the local file.

```
var loader:URLLoader = new URLLoader();
loader.addEventListener(Event.COMPLETE, useData);
loader.load(new URLRequest("abc.txt"));

function useData(event:Event):void {
  var data:String = event.target.data.toString();
   myTextField.text = data;
}
```

Comment: It is not possible to access local files from a swf running in the browser. You will have to use AIR to perform any tasks with the local file system. Refer to @BerggreenDK's answer if you are able to use AIR instead.

Comment: I am not using AIR and doesn't the url say it is possible ? http://probertson.com/articles/2006/10/06/local-remote-resources-local-swf/ am I missing any AIR parts ? I have tested it and it shows the content of the "abc.txt" file.

Comment: When you grab the abc.txt file, it's in the same directory as the swf. That's why you have access to it.

Comment: it also works if do it for "C:\\folder\abc.txt" ,  I Have tested it!

Comment: There is a security issue. When the SWF is on the web, you cannot access content on the desktop. When the SWF is on the desktop, by default you cannot access content from the web (unless the SWF is in a whitelisted directory). This is a security feature, not a bug. You simply cannot access a local file from the web using Flash (other than using `FileReference`, as pointed out by frankhermes)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can present the user with a standard OS window to open a file they can select themselves from their filesystem.

from the manual: [FileReference.browse](http://help.adobe.com/en_US/FlashPlatform/reference/actionscript/3/flash/net/FileReference.html#browse%28%29):

> Displays a file-browsing dialog box that lets the user select a file to upload. The dialog box is native to the user's operating system. The user can select a file on the local computer or from other systems, for example, through a UNC path on Windows.

So even though you cannot list the files in a directory yourself, you can prompt the user to select a file for you.